# Secure sync of TrueCrypt containers on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, security, sync

Need to sync arbitrary files within two TrueCrypt containers; one container is a backup, the other the one actively used by me, both are local during the transaction.

Current concern security wise is that there would be "data leaks" that would result from the sync tool being used; for example, the sync tool producing indexes that when be stored unencrypted on disk.

Any suggestions, or insights into the possible attack vectors that might result from using a sync tool as described?

Comment: I think this would depend on the sync tool you use - do you have one in mind, or a shortlist?

Comment: @Geoff: Agree, though security is the most important factor to me. If it matters, I've used [SyncToy](http://www.google.com/search?q=SyncToy) before, and it also appears to be a [popular suggestion for a sync tool on Super User](http://superuser.com/search?q=synctoy). If you have any more questions, or suggestions, just let me know, thanks!